# How do I make it so i can tab through the whole form?

Tags: html, forms

I am creating a form for a website, but right now it's only allowing me to tab through from phone down. I cannot tab from first name to last name to phone. how do I change it to allow me to tab through the whole thing?

```
<form data-customer-information-form="true" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="addticket/submit" name="ticketForm" id="ticketform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <p>
                <label for="customerFirstName">First Name:</label></br>
                <input type="text" name="customerFirstName" id="customerFirstName" placeholder="first name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="customerLastName">Last Name:</label></br>
                <input type="text" name="customerLastName" id="customerLastName" placeholder="last name" required>
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone: used for contact</label></br>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" maxlength="12" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email:</label></br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="service">Computer/Service Name:</label></br>
                <input type="text" name="service" placeholder="computer model or service" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="description">Anything else we need to know:</label></br>
                <textarea type="text" maxlength="200" name="description" id="description" placeholder="What's gone wrong?"></textarea>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form>
```

When I copied the HTML into an HTML viewer it works fine. But in the rest of the page it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it's not letting you tab as is, but you could try setting the `tabindex` property:

```html
<form data-customer-information-form="true" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="addticket/submit" name="ticketForm" id="ticketform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <p>
                <label for="customerFirstName">First Name:</label></br>
                <input tabindex="0" type="text" name="customerFirstName" id="customerFirstName" placeholder="first name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="customerLastName">Last Name:</label></br>
                <input tabindex="0" type="text" name="customerLastName" id="customerLastName" placeholder="last name" required>
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone: used for contact</label></br>
                <input tabindex="0" type="tel" id="phone" maxlength="12" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email:</label></br>
                <input tabindex="0" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="service">Computer/Service Name:</label></br>
                <input tabindex="0" type="text" name="service" placeholder="computer model or service" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="description">Anything else we need to know:</label></br>
                <textarea tabindex="0" type="text" maxlength="200" name="description" id="description" placeholder="What's gone wrong?"></textarea>
            </p>
            <input tabindex="0" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javascript isn't preventing certain keys.

```
document.getElementById("customerFirstName").onkeydown = function(e){
            if(!(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode ===46 || keypress.keyCode === 9)){
            if(!(/[A-Za-z]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)))) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            }
            }
        }
```